# Retain/release with ARC is slowing me down

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using ARC in my iOS app. I have profiled the method below and even though the algorithm is terribly naive and wasteful 77% of the time is spent in `objc_retain` and `objc_release`. I think it must be down to the line where i fetch a Unit from the `NSArray` and ARC is careful to retain and then release the object each time.

I'm looking for an informed advice: how do I fix it elegantly?

```
-(CGFloat)getUncertaintyForUnits:(NSArray*)units Position:(MKMapPoint)position Zoom:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale {

    CGFloat closest = MAXFLOAT; 

    for (int i = 0; i < [units count]; i++) {
        Unit *units = (Unit*)[units objectAtIndex:i];

        CGFloat distance = [self distanceBetweenMapPoints:unit.mapPoint And:position];

        if (distance < closest) {
            closest = distance;
        }
    }

    CGFloat max = 100 / zoomScale;
    return  (1. - closest / max) * 0.9;
}
```

Comment: just a side note: the [naming conventions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000146i) would say, that ` distanceBetweenMapPoints:And:` is a quite bad name. it is `camelCase:forAllParameters:`. `and…` would indicated, that a certain action might be triggered, instead you are asked to use `with…:`. sou in your case the best name would be: `distanceBetweenMapPoint:position:`

Comment: Thanks, I'll read through the naming conventions to be spot on next time :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you could try [fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html):

```
for (Unit *unit in units) {
    CGFloat distance = [self distanceBetweenMapPoints:unit.mapPoint And:position];
    if (distance < closest) {
        closest = distance;
    }
}
```

this should avoid extra retains/releases, as in fast enumeration the whole array is blocked.

> There are several advantages to using fast enumeration:
>
> - The enumeration is considerably more efficient than, for example,
>     using NSEnumerator directly.
> - The syntax is concise.
> - Enumeration is
>     “safe”—the enumerator has a mutation guard so that if you attempt to
>     modify the collection during enumeration, an exception is raised.

Comment: Will this be more or less the same as using `getObjects:range:`?

Comment: Fast enumeration is generally much faster than `getObjects:range:`, particularly for a single enumeration. `getObjects:range:` makes a copy. Fast enumeration doesn't.

Comment: Indeed. Fast enumeration is a fantastic Objective-C feature which gives the compiler more information about what you want to accomplish so that it can do its job better.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need memory managed objects for some reason, one faster alternative would be to store your position points in regular C arrays (or an array of structs).

Objective C is a superset of regular ANSI C.  Sometimes the benefits of the OOP superset constructs do no outweigh the costs in object runtime messaging and management in inner loops.